# How to ensure that the library/package that I'm maintaining is backward compatible?

Tags: .net, maven, npm, nuget

I'm maintaining a library/package that's distributed via a package manager (NuGet, Maven, NPM, etc ...it doesn't matter) and there has been too many times where my new package accidentally broke backwards compatibility.

For example, one time I mindlessly added a parameter to a method without realizing that it breaks backwards compatibility.

How do you ensure that your package is backwards compatibility? Do you have any automated tests? If so, what kind? Or do you just rely on code reviewers? Answers for .Net would be great but an answer for any language is highly appreciated as well.

Thanks

Comment: First do you have unit tests?

Comment: We have unit tests but they don't guard against interface changes. For example, I could add an optional parameter in a method in C# and the unit test will happily compile but it could be a breaking change to the consumers of the library because the method signature has change (even though the parameter is optional) - this has happened before.

Comment: But one of your usages should fail when it's being compiled? Doesn't that in C# ?...like using an interface which has changed. I would also suggest to create kind of reference implementation (which checks the usage from the users perspective). Also if you have optional parameters you should have tests which check them apart that I usually find optional parameters a bit strange while using an interfaces...In Java thinks like https://revapi.org/ exist (several other tools as well)...to help here... You should find a tool which helps here...

Comment: The code will recompile when I update the library. However, things break if I don't recompile and just directly use the latest library. Tools just like you suggested would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Roslyn team created a code analyzer that helps. There are [instructions on GitHub on how to use it](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/PublicApiAnalyzers/PublicApiAnalyzers.Help.md).

Basically you add the [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers) to your project. If you manually edit your project file/msbuild files, be sure to add `PrivateAssets="all"` to the `PackageReference`, to avoid this package becoming a dependency of your package and forcing your package consumers to use the analyzer by accident).

Then, when you build your project, the analyzer will complain if any public API isn't defined in a `PublicAPI.Shipped.txt` or `PublicAPI.Unshipped.txt` file. This helps you detect when someone adds a new API, so code reviewers can decide if that's an API the support should support. There's also a rule to complain if an API defined in one of the text files was not found in the code. This tells everyone than an API was broken. [There are some other analyzers/rules in the package](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/PublicApiAnalyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.PublicApiAnalyzers.md), which help in keeping APIs stable and increasing the quality of APIs for package consumers.

When a new API is added, there's a code fix to add the new API to the `PublicAPI.Unshipped.txt` file. How you use `PublicAPI.Unshipped.txt` and `PublicAPI.Shipped.txt` is up to you, but our team moves all contents from unshipped to shipped after we publish our packages to nuget.org. This means if a pull request removes or changes an API in `PublicAPI.Unshipped.txt`, it's not a breaking change because that API was never available in a package on nuget.org.

My team hasn't yet implemented any automation around public API changes in pull requests. But depending on how sophisticated your CI pipeline is, you can also enforce a stricter policy regarding public API changes. For example, using GitHub webhooks, you can:

- When a PR gets a "PublicAPI:changed" label, use the GitHub Checks API to block the PR from being merged. If label is removed, then unblock the PR from being merged.
- When a PR with the "PublicAPI:changed" label gets the "PublicAPI:approved" label, use GitHub Checks to unblock the PR from being merged. Similarly, if the approved label is removed, but the chaned label stays, again block the PR from being merged.
- When a PR is created, or a new commit is added, check the diff between the PR target branch, and if there are any `PublicAPI.[Unshipped|Shipped].txt` files changed, then automatically add the "PublicApi:changed" label. If the PR already had the "PublicAPI:changed" label, but the PR no longer contains any `PublicAPI.*.txt` changes, then remove the "PublicAPI:changed" label.

  - It's up to you whether or not to remove the "PublicAPI:approved" label when new commits are pushed. It depends how often/likely someone with a PR with approved API makes another public API change and tries to sneak it in without another public API approval. On the other hand, if the PR needs a minor fix unrelated to public APIs, it can be annoying to request someone approve the public APIs again.

Anyway, all that's just an idea. So far we just manually notice when a PR contains a public API txt file change, and ping other people in the team for reviews as needed.

Comment: That's a nice library. However, developers still need to be aware that adding an optional parameters will require the consumers of the library to recompile their code but I guess there is no better tool at this point.

Comment: The analyzer actually puts the default file in PublicAPI.*.txt, so it becomes painfully obvious that changing the default value affects package consumers. My suggestion is to impose a team rule that optional parameters on public APIs are banned. Instead, create overloads, where the overload with fewer parameters calls the one with the most parameters, with the default values. That way the default value is not part of the public API and doesn't "need" a recompile.